# Python 3.6 - cx_Oracle gets different output from SQL Developer

Tags: sql, python-3.x, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

Running a simple select all query. Python cx_Oracle gives me 150,529 rows while SQL developer gives me 229079 rows. Any thoughts?

Below is the query I ran in SQL developer.

```
SELECT *
FROM VERIFICATION
WHERE VERIF_SUBTYPE_C = 1000
```

Below is my python code

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(con_str)

SQL = """
SELECT *
FROM VERIFICATION
WHERE VERIF_SUBTYPE_C = 1000
"""
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(SQL)
verif = pd.read_sql(SQL,connection)
```

Comment: the most likely reasons for these types of things - you're in a different database or a different schema between the two environments

Comment: or a pending transaction in one or the other.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith  I think you are right... Thank god I asked!